# Return entries in DataFrame where logic statement passes

Tags: python, pandas

How can boolean statements be used to filter column data?

E.g. Get index and value of rows in `dataframe['score']` where `value != 0`

Where `dataframe['score']` contains data in the following format

```
0      0
1      1
2      0
3      3
4      0
      ..
100    0
101    9
102    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of readability. Use `pd.DataFrame.query`:

```
df.query('score != 0')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, returns all columns in original set too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try a boolean query and mask

```
df[df.score.ne(0)]

      score
1        1
3        3
101      9
102      7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code:

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import random
d = {'score': [random.randint(0,1) for x in range(10)]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


print(df)

print(df[df.score != 0])
```

**Input**

```
   score
0      0
1      0
2      1
3      0
4      1
5      0
6      0
7      1
8      1
9      0
```

**Output**

```
   score
2      1
4      1
7      1
8      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'score':[0,1,3,0]})
>>> dataframe[dataframe['score']!=0]
   score
1      1
2      3
```

Notes:

- `dataframe['score']!=0` creates a *mask* of boolean values per each row, if the `score` value is not equal to `0`, it is `True`, else, `False`
- `dataframe[...]` just keeps the values that have `True` in the mask.